# Creating a drop down selection box populated by specific model field

Tags: html, django, django-models

I am trying to figure out the best way to create a method for users to add other existing users to a Task. My idea was to have an dropdown selection box where the users are listed and then can be added to a Task. Is there an easy way to populate a dropdown menu from a model and on submit, add the selected user to the relevant Task object

```
class CustomUser(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, null=True)

class Task(models.Model):
   users = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do something special.  Just use the regular django [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/):

```
class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('users', )
```

The `users` field will be presented as the multiple select widget with a list of `CustomUser`s.

If you want to use some other form to manage users then the [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) is the way to go:

```
class AddUserForm(forms.Form):
    user = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=CustomUser.objects.all())
```

Comment: I based on surface testing the 2nd version works way easier with my current setup. Thank you